# Dictionary with object - warning Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, nullable-reference-types

This dictionary can accept on object of any type, but throws a *CS8600 Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type* when assigning the output as a named variable, followed by a *CS8602 Dereference of a possibly null reference* when using "value" later.

```
    Dictionary<string, object> objects = new();
    if(objects.TryGetValue("IntObjectName", out object value))
    {
      var intValue = (int)value;
    }
    if(objects.TryGetValue("StringObjectName", out object value))
    {
      var stringValue = (string)value;
    }
```

**What is the proper way to write this so that the nullable reference warnings are not thrown?**

This pattern is used to receive a dictionary of parameters of various different types.  The collection needs to accept any type of object, but the implementing service will know how to deal with the specific names and objects.(Account, Customer, etc)

I'm hoping there is a way to indicate the object is not null, rather than suppressing the null warning or just using a nullable object.  A parameter must have a value (not null) to be added to the collection.

---

I'm using this to build up an linq query expression tree in which a collection of parameter values are passed in and each method checks to see if its expression is needed, depending on which fields have inputs.  Each method is responsible for converting and sanitizing the user input and implementing its relevant logic.

```
  private static IQueryable<CutInFlatWorkflowJob> WhereBillAccountKey(Dictionary<string, object> parameters, IQueryable<CutInFlatWorkflowJob> query)
  {
    if (!parameters.TryGetValue("BillAccountKey", out object value)) return query;
    var clean = value.ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty);
    if (int.TryParse(clean, out int account))
    {
      return query.Where(x => x.Workflow.Source.BillAccountKey == account);
    }
    else
    {
      return query.Where(x => 0 == 1);
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you don't know even the type of the object, why do you care about if it's nullable? If its only the warning, just supress it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. If you're casting `value` as an int, why not use a dictionary of `<string, int>`? Can you add a bit more context please?

Comment: @Skettenring probably is keeping several kind of data by a string identifier and working with that in several conversions, this code (far of my taste, I would use reflection) is conventional used in template fill up and template conversions

Comment: _casting_ to int is different that _parsing_ a string to an int. If the dictionary holds numbers and strings that represent numbers, you need to handle those separately, or use a more generic method like `Convert.ToInt32` and deal with exceptions. And you need to decide what to do if the value _can't_ be converted to an `int.`

Comment: @LeandroBardelli yeah I'm just wondering if generics might be better depending on what they're actually trying to do (i.e. perform similar operations on classes that all derive from the same base type). Maybe not a good solution if that's not what they're trying to do. :)

Comment: Reflection is expensive in general and compared to generics is always worse in terms of cost.

Comment: I've updated the question with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the project is set with `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`, declare the `out` variables as nullable, e.g. not `object` but `object?`. Essentially you are declaring that the value could be null and hence there is no warning. You can also use `var`, e.g. `out var value`.

```
Dictionary<string, object> objects = new()
{
    { "IntObjectName", null },
    { "StringObjectName", null }
};
if (objects.TryGetValue("IntObjectName", out object? value0) && null != value0)
{
    var intValue = (int)value0;
}
if (objects.TryGetValue("StringObjectName", out object? value1) && null != value1)
{
    var stringValue = (string)value1;
}
```

The dictionary values in the example code are actually `null`. Although there won't be a compiler warning, the cast of a null will be a runtime exception.

There were changes for nullable analysis/checking introduced with .Net 6. See [Nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references).

Comment: I know the objects will not be null and am hoping there is a way to indicate this and resolve the warning instead of declaring it nullable.

Comment: @WesH: When you say you "know the objects will not be null" do you mean you know the dictionary will have those keys? Or just that if the key is found in the dictionary _then_ the value associated with that key will not be null?

Comment: If the key is found, the value is not null.  A UI method walks the input fields and only adds parameters to the dictionary if the input field has a value.  Then it passes the dictionary to the search service.  Within that service, each expression method determines if it is needed if its key value is present and updates the linq query accordingly.

Comment: The out value may not be null, but it is tagged as nullable and causes the warnings.

Comment: @WesH: The value actually can be null if `TryGetValue` returns false, and you'd want to help developers avoid trying to use the variable in that case. So you can declare the out variable as an `object?` like this answer says (or as an `out var`), and you'll get correct semantics. The compiler will know that the variable is not null inside of your `if` block because `TryGetValue` returned false.

Comment: That makes sense. It looks like my options are to accept the warning in the TryGetValue, or declare it as object? and use null conditional operators within if statement.  I was hoping there was a better way, but that is what I needed to know.

Comment: Actually, value0 can be null and TryGetValue would be still true. Then, the cast (int)value0 will throw an Exception. You may consider testing whether value0 is null and handle the situation before cast.

Comment: @Codigo You are correct. I was focused on the compiler warning. I made an edit.